# Clean AddThis / Facebook Like / Recommend Button without Social Text?

Tags: facebook, addthis

I've been desperately seeking a way to disable the facebook social text right next to the "Recommend" button. Is it possible, to simply render a "Recommend" button, without anything else (no counter, no text, JUST the button)?

The problem is, CSS wont be applied since all the elements are inside the iframe, so I cant just hide the element itself using CSS (which in this case would be a td).

Also, I cant just put everything in a div and give it overflow:hidden and a fix width, since the pop up which appears when actually clicking the "Recommend" Button would then not be fully visible.

My current implementation comes via AddThis:

```
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:size="small" fb:like:layout="none" fb:like:action="recommend" fb:like:width="10"></a>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 2):

[Facebook polcy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#policies) IV 4 d:

> You must not obscure or cover elements of our social plugins, such as the Like button or Like box plugin.

So if you can't do it by using their [like button creation tool](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) you shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Add This Facebook Like button you can avoid the count using this attribute

```
fb:like:layout="button"
```

So in your case you would have

```
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:size="small" fb:like:layout="button" fb:like:action="recommend" ></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

"Recommend" with a counter comes closest to your request. I too don't like the social text (e.g. "57 people like this. Be the first of your friends"), yet I do like the naked counter. The code that I use is:

```
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count" fb:like:action="recommend" fb:like:width="135"></a>
```

See AddThis own documentation [here](http://www.addthis.com/help/third-party-buttons#facebook-like).